# Como aplicar uma textura sem distorcer?

Tags: android

Eu tenho uma textura como esta, que vou aplicar em vários formatos e tamanhos diferentes, além de fundo de tabela e linhas de tabela.

Como fazer para aplicar ela em vários tamanhos sem distorcer? É possivel?

OBS: Utilizei o ninepatch mas por ser uma textura, acabou distorcendo a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vá ao XML do seu *drawable* e adicione a propriedade `tileMode="repeat"`. Por exemplo:

**`drawable/imagem_de_fundo.xml`**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/imagem_de_fundo_real"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Depois use o `@drawable/imagem_de_fundo` como sua imagem, ela vai escalonar se repetindo ao invés de receber zoom.